# Как ввести дату и вручную в телеграм бота Java

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Перерыл весь гугл,результата нет,может кто то сталкивался .
нужно чтобы пользотель вводил дату и время вручную или еще каким то образом,может какой то формой готовой,чтобы строго получалсь yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss в телеграм боте
написаном на java.
видел что то похожее на питоне у людей,там выпадает календарь и пользователь выбирает дату и время.есть ли что то подобное на java и где это найти или у кого то может есть готовый код.помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Никакой календарь ниоткуда вам не выпадет в официальном клиенте для любой из платформ, потому что такой фичи нет в Bot API. Вы можете это реализовать посредством инлайн- или обычной клавиатуры.